# Creating Adaptive Icons with <maskable-icon>

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to implement  with this guide:

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/adaptive-icons.html#Creating

for Android O Preview but the launcher shows me the default Android icon and not the two layers indicated in my ic_launcher.xml

> ic_launcher.xml

```
<maskable-icon>
   <background android:drawable="@mipmap/layer0"/>
   <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/layer1"/>
</maskable-icon>
```

Has anyone tried to implement this? Or is not still available?

(In my manifest I put the ic_launcher.xml in icon)

***UPDATE:***
Google updates your website and put `adaptive-icon` instead `maskable-icon`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out an answer when I check the file below.

```
\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-O\data\res\drawable\sym_def_app_icon.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/sym_def_app_icon_maskable" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

I don't know which is eventually right.
But for now(preview 1), adaptive-icon tag seems to work correctly.

Comment: worked for me. see the corresponding issue here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36535386

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to define it in the manifest?

```
<application
        ...
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        ...>

    ...

</application>
```

Comment: No... Obviously I put in the manifest, I don't have other icons in mipmap only this maskable icon...

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file too:

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: This is not needed.